# SIGSEGV on dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

I am trying to dynamic_cast, one virtual class, to another:

```
SomeClass::SomeFunc(_AListner& listner)
_BListner* listner = dynamic_cast<_BListner*>(&listner)
```

Please note that class _BListner is derived from class _AListner.

But I get this error on debugging:

```
SIGSEGV, Segmentaion fault.

<some address> in  __dynamic_cast () from /usr/lib/libstdc++
```

Comment: Can you show the code that invokes `SomeFunc()` ? Of particular interest is the lifetime of `listner`.

Comment: Also, you should use a different naming convention: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier : `Each name that [...] begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter is reserved to the implementation for any use.`

Comment: Could be anything, post the code.

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for reply
Moreover  SomeFunc() is a callback function from somewhere else.so I dont know what exactly appens there. Also the parameters are not nulls.

Comment: @V.KSingh, a non-null argument does not guarantee that object being pointed to or referred to exists.

Comment: @hmjd- yes I know and after dynamic_cast listner is null. any idea how to catch exception thrown by dynamic_catch and why is it null or how to check if the address shown is valid or not? I am doing gdb debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SIGSEGV can be triggered by `dynamic_cast` when:

- the object has a wild address
- the object's metadata (typically vtable pointer) has been corrupted
- the object doesn't match the static type of the expression

or

- the expression doesn't have polymorphic type (that means the static type of the expression passed to `dynamic_cast`, not merely the dynamic type of the object it points into).

The last case should be caught by the compiler though.

Comment: I had this problem when I `dynamic_cast`'ed a pointer that I had taken from a `std::vector<...>::iterator` which had been invalidated by erasing elements of the vector. I think that counts as having a wild address.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned _BListner is derived from _AListner. Do you have any third party class like _CListner which is also derivde from _AListner? If so, passing a _CListner Object to your function is allowed, but the dynamic_cast fails and throws an exception of type std::bad_cast. Not catching that exception eventually may result in SIGSEGV.

Just an assumption, you definitely need to provide more information.

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for reply
there is nothing like _CListner.
Moreover  SomeFunc() is a callback function from somewhere else.so I dont know what exactly appens there. Also the parameters are not nulls.

Comment: Try to call any virtual method from listener just before doing dynamic_cast. If the listener is corrupted this will probably result a crash, and at least you will know that the problem is not in dynamic_cast. Also using of tools like Valgrind may be helpful.

Comment: The dynamic_cast will _not_ throw std::bad_cast in the example. dynamic_cast simply returns NULL when used with a pointer argument that cannot be casted.

Comment: @Black:But that is not being the case. if it returns null, I can handle but it is crashing with SIGSEGV.

Comment: @Singh: Do you handle the NULL pointer? If not, it may cause the SIGSEGV. The point I want to make is that sebms' answer is wrong. dynamic_cast doesn't throw exceptions with pointer arguments and an uncaught std::bad_cast does not cause SIGSEGV but a call to `terminate()` (see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/exception/terminate/ )